# Passing arguments from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the PHP code . I am try to call edit_course() function defined in javascript , passing arguments . But not able to complete the task .There is some problem with this piece of code. But I am not able to figure out .
Is there some better way to do so, which is not so messed up ?
Help will be appreciated.

php

```
$course_result = $con->query("SELECT * from course_records where institute_id='".$row['institute_id']."' ");

$course=$course_result->fetch_assoc();
echo "<div class='options'> <span  ><div class='round-button' id='".$course["course_id"]."' onclick='edit_course(".$course['course_id'].",".$course['subject'].")'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label class='lblname' >Edit</label></span>";
```

javascript

```
function edit_course(course,institute){
    alert(course);
   alert(institute);}
```

The output is blank page.

Comment: id='".$course["course_id"]."'onclick=  .. there is no space between id and onclick

Comment: can you post the generated HTML, that will help us figure out the issue.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal it shows empty page.

Comment: subject is a string, you have to put quotes around it to generate valid Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this, there were some errors:

```
echo "<div class='options'><span><div class='round-button' id='".$course["course_id"]."'
                            onclick='edit_course(".$course['course_id'].",".$course['subject'].")'><div>
        class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label class='lblname'>Edit</label></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc() returns an array http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php , you can not use it in the way you are using it, you should iterate over the array to return the results, like this:

```
 $course_result = $con->query("SELECT * from course_records where institute_id='".$row['institute_id']."' ");

$course=$course_result->fetch_assoc();
foreach($course as $value){
 echo "<div class='options'> <span  ><div class='round-button' id='".$value["course_id"]."' onclick='edit_course(".$value['course_id'].",".$value['subject'].")'><div class='round-button-circle'></div></div> <label class='lblname' >Edit</label></span>";
   }
```

Comment: actually I am doing like this only , I removed the loop for simplification purposes . This also is not working